# Custom Scope with ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, scope, google-search-console

I have made a custom script to made some calls to the Google Webmaster Tools API.

Now I found the function `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`. So I thought I maybe able to skip the complete custom getting-a-new-token process.

But how can I add a custom scope to the project property scopes, as documented in the [Google Webmaster docs](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, 
In the script editor klik: Resources and then Advanced google services.
Enable the Google Analytics API and klick on the link Google Developers Console to enable the API.

After that you can make API calls without the need of programming oAuth2.0 scopes.
See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics

Comment: This is not the API I want to get. You meant the analytics API, but what I need is the Webmasters-API (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly). I want to get data like crawling-errors and sitemap information.

Comment: Sorry did not read good enough, well then you have to program the whole OAUTH2.0 flow from scratch. Here is the example (i tried this and it works): https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

Also you should put in a feature request to add the Webmaster Tools API to the advanced google services if you post me the feature request ill star it:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request%20from%20user

Comment: Okay, done ;) https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5194